# why v3 does not return anything even when inputs are equal

Tags: c++, vector, output, logic

i need to push same elements form v1 and v2 to v3
why the v3 vector is still empty when inputs are like

- *v1 :1 2 3 4 5*
- *v2:3 4 5 6 7 8*

is the logic flawed or help?

so on Using the **STL** function it gives **seg fault** 
but if i increase the size of v3 then the unwanted 0's gets printed 
v3 just needs to be the same elements in v1 v2

```
vector<int> commonElements(vector<int>v1, vector<int>v2)
{
    vector<int>v3;

   // set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),v3.begin());
   for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<v2.size();j++)
    {
        if(v1[i]==v2[j])
            v3.push_back(v1[i]);
    }

    return v3;
}
```

Comment: You start the j loop at `i+i`, so you only check for the last part of v2. Start at j=0

Comment: `std::set_intersection` does all of this work using `std::back_inserter`.  Why did you comment it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no need to abandon `std::set_intersection`.  The issue is that the container receiving the results need to be sized appropriately to hold the results.

An empty vector can be used if you used the `std::back_inserter()` iterator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> commonElements(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    std::vector<int> v3;
    set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
    return v3;
}

int main()
{
   auto test = commonElements({1,2,3,4,5}, {4,5,6,7,8});
   for (auto &v : test )
     std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

For your function to work (and for `std::set_intersection` to work) both containers `v1` and `v2` must be sorted.

Once the containers are sorted you can use `std::set_intersection`. Your only mistake was the usage of `v3`:

```
set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```

since your vector `v3` was empty the iterator would reach invalid state immediatly if you just pass `v3.begin()`. A `back_inserter` will basically grow the vector automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `for` must be `j = 0` not `j = i+1`:

```
   for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<v2.size();j++)
    {
        if(v1[i]==v2[j])
            v3.push_back(v1[i]);
    }
```